# How to turn formula to variables for use with fastLm function in R

Tags: r, data.table, rcpparmadillo

I am trying to use function `RcppArmadillo::fastLM` instead of `lm` for performance reasons.
Here is my function call to `lm`

```
test_dt = structure(list(A= c(168.08, 166.65, 167.52, 167.16, 165.77, 
167.65, 169.84, 170.45, 171.29, 173.15, 174.12, 174.45, 174.18, 
172.92, 174.5, 173.94, 172.61, 168.74, 167.28, 167.12), `B` = c(1801.599976, 
1783, 1795.099976, 1788.699951, 1763.599976, 1793, 1816.400024, 
1827.400024, 1830.199951, 1847.599976, 1863.199951, 1867.900024, 
1866.099976, 1853.599976, 1869.699951, 1861, 1851.199951, 1806, 
1783.5, 1784.099976)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))

coef(lm(A ~ B + 0,data = test_dt))[1]

> 0.0934728
```

since most of the time is used by lm in interpreting formula, I do not want to use formula. Instead, I want to turn it into something -

```
RcppArmadillo::fastLM(X = test_dt$B + 0, y = test_dt$A)
```

but I am not sure how to add `+ 0` as shown in the formula.

I have tried the following

```
library(data.table)
dt = copy(test_dt)
dt[, C := 0]
coef(RcppArmadillo::fastLm(X = dt[,2:3], y = dt[,1]))[[1]]
```

But this is giving error.

```
Error in fastLm.default(X = dt[, 2:3], y = dt[, 1]) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

Can someone show me the right way to turn formula `A ~ B + 0` into variables `X` and `y` for use in fastLm function?

Here are the performance results.

```
 microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  formula = coef(lm(A ~ B + 0, dt))[1],
  fastLm = with(dt, coef(RcppArmadillo::fastLm(B, A)))[1],
  flm = with(dt, collapse::flm(A, cbind(B)))[1],
  times = 100)
```

```
Unit: microseconds
    expr      min       lq       mean    median        uq      max neval cld
 formula 1157.822 1173.249 1191.57071 1183.0080 1197.5560 1714.430   100   c
  fastLm  219.785  228.086  240.30415  235.2545  244.7465  405.353   100  b 
     flm   67.595   71.902   76.91765   74.7790   77.2050  228.320   100 a
```

Comment: Can you try the formula method ie. `fastLm(A ~ B + 0, data = dt)`

Comment: Formula method is working fine. The only problem is that using formula is 3 times slower.

Comment: In the first formula you were using `A ~ B + 0`, but in second you are using `y` as `B`, is it a typo

Comment: Yes, it was a typo, I have corrected it. Thanks.

Comment: Do you need `fastLm(X = dt[, 2:3], y = dt[[1]])`

Comment: It worked! However it is throwing a warining ```warning: solve(): system is singular; attempting approx solution
```

Comment: That warning is based on your data and the methods used by fastLm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument of the default method of fastLm is the model matrix. It should have a column of 1's to represent the intercept and if it does not then there is no intercept.

These give the same answer using no intercept:

```
coef(lm(A ~ B + 0, test_dt))[1]
with(test_dt, coef(fastLm(B, A)))
```

and these give the same answer using an intercept:

```
coef(lm(A ~ B, test_dt))
with(test_dt, coef(fastLm(cbind(1, B), A)))
```

Comment: Thanks, @Grothendieck, it worked perfectly. I have shared the performance results above.

Comment: You could also try flm in the collapse package.  It uses the same arguments as fastLm but in the opposite order and it returns only the coefficients so one does not use coef with it.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I tried ```library(collapse)
  with(dt, collapse::flm(X = B, y = A, method = "lm"))```, but it is throwing error ```if (n != NROW(y)) stop("NROW(y) must match nrow(X)")```. Seems like inside ```flm``` function both ```dim(dt$A)``` and ```nrow(dt$B)``` are failing.

Comment: Using the test_dt from the question these both work for me:  `library(collapse); with(test_dt, flm(A, cbind(B)))` - seems that B can't be a vector but must be a matrix, and using the same library statement:  `with(test_dt, flm(A, cbind(1, B)))`

Comment: Wow, ```flm``` is even faster. I have updated the performance results. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The `y` should be a vector. According to `?fastLm`

> y - a vector containing the explained variable.

By using `dt[,1]`, the `drop = FALSE` in `data.table` which returns a data.table with single column.  Instead, if we want a vector, use `[[` to extract the column

```
fastLm(X = dt[, 2:3], y = dt[[1]])
```

Comment: Is there a way to remove the warning? ```solve(): system is singular; attempting approx solution```

Comment: @Saurabh when you say remove the warning, do you want `suppressWarnings`

Comment: No :), I meant is there something else I am doing wrong while calling ```fastLm```. I tried turning X to matrix but still the error is there.